# Cannot Import Machine learning dependencies

Tags: s4sdk

I'm trying to incorporate a Machine learning service using s4sdk archetype.I could not load the ML dependencies. Do I need to add it explicitly in pom.xml or is it part of the s4 archetype.

I was trying it as per the below blog 
Here's [link](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/07/29/production-ready-integration-of-sap-leonardo-machine-learning-foundation-services-with-an-sap-s4hana-side-by-side-extension-built-with-the-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk/)

The below dependencies which could not be loaded

import com.sap.cloud.sdk.services.scp.machinelearning.LeonardoMlFoundation;
Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Hey Arun, just a reminder: If the answer solved your issue, please mark it as "accepted" so that others can easily see this is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you're missing the dependency

```
<groupId>com.sap.cloud.s4hana.services</groupId>
<artifactId>scp-machine-learning</artifactId>
```

in your `pom.xml` file. Once this is added, it should work.

Best regards

Florian